# What does double colon mean in SML when summing up list of numbers?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I cannot quite understand the logic behind following function. This function is used to sum up the numbers in the list. But the tutor doesn't tell much about what `::` does here.
The original list in the tutorial has 5 numbers/items in the list (1,3,5,7,9). I thought that tutor named these items with five letters (a,r,e,s,t) first, but function still works for the lists that has items more or less than 5. So how come is that?

```
- fun sum([]) = 0 | sum(a::rest)= a + sum(rest);
```

The `a` `rest` is not a language-specific command here as long as I know. They must be just user defined.

I found the information below in the SML Documentation which still didn't make any sense to grasp `::` concept.

```
datatype 'a list = nil | :: of 'a * 'a list
```

Comment: With `::` You are just decomposing the list (in advance) into the first element (`a` in Your case) and a tail (or the `rest`): `a` and `rest` are just variables and You are free to name them as You wish.

Comment: @barti_ddu Got you! Based on the list above, this must be like: when a=1, the rest=3 and new "a" from now on is 1+3=4. Then a=4, the rest=5, and the new "a" from now on is 4+5=9.. and so on.

Comment: Not exactly: the `tail` is the remainder of the list after the decomposition (the list minus the first element), i.e. `[3; 5; 7; 9]` after the first iteration, `[5; 7; 9]` after the second and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @barti_ddu I want to answer the question.

Decomposition of the list [1,3,5,7,9] works as follows:

```
- fun sum([]) = 0 | sum(first::tail)= first + sum(tail);
```

`first` means the first item (1) in the list.

`tail` means the remaining items (3,5,7,9) in the list after taking out the first item (1)

So it looks like:

```
1 + sum([3,5,7,9])
```

What does `sum([3,5,7,9])` equal to? Well, according to the function above it equals to:

```
sum(first::tail)= first + sum(tail)
```

in other 'words':

```
sum([3,5,7,9])= 3 + sum([5,7,9])
```

Let's not forget about the `1 + sum([3,5,7,9])` above and show the whole string:

```
1 + 3 + sum([5,7,9])
```

If we repeat it until the end of the string, it will be like this:

```
1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9 + sum([])
```

and this will eventually equal to `25 + sum([])`

From the function above `sum([])` equals to `0` (zero).

So the results is 25 + 0 = 25.

Note: If we were to write, let's say, `5` in place of `0` for the empty list, the result would equal to 25 + 5 = **30**